# Node.js findOne returns null with status code 200 looking in a mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to query a mongoDB database.

I have declared my Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const CosmeticSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    code: String,
    url: String,
    creator: String,
 ----------------- omitted -----------------
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Cosmetics_DB_original', CosmeticSchema, 'comestics_collections');
```

I have required it and I am trying to query the field code:

```
const Note = require('./models/Cosmetic');

module.exports.getByNum = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  connectToDatabase()
    .then(() => {
      var movie="00037541"
      Note.findOne({"code":movie}, function (err, note) {
        if (err){
          console.log(err)
        }
        else{
          console.log("Result : ", note);
        }
      })
        .then(note => callback(null, {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify(note)
        }))
        .catch(err => callback(null, {
          statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
          body: 'Could not fetch the note.'
        }));
    });
};
```

This results in a 500 status code but the console shows
Result: null

Making a getAll request returns a status code 200 but the body is just []

```
module.exports.getAll = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  connectToDatabase()
    .then(() => {
      Note.find()
        .then(notes => callback(null, {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify(notes)
        }))
        .catch(err => callback(null, {
          statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
          body: 'Could not fetch the notes.'
        }))
    });
};
```

and making a findById returns a status code of 200 but null on the body.

All the questions I found on stackoverflow end up with the users who posted the question realizing they were querying the wrong database but I'm pretty sure mine is correct. Having a collection name of comestics_collection and comestics_collection**s** yields the same results. Please help

[image: databse and collection name]

Comment: Why do you use both callback function and a promise to handle `findOne`? I'm pretty sure that when you use callback this doesn't return a promise anymore.

Comment: Don't clear why you expect an error. An empty result doesn't throw an exception. If you need an error status code, you should process it separately

Comment: @KonradLinkowski to be honest I know nothing about this and the mongoose docs always leave me with more questions than I first started with. If you happen to know a good basics tutorial that would be great.

Comment: @MaximSharai see my comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I wasn't specifying the database in my mongoDB URI

DB=mongodb+srv://{user}:{password}@{cluster name}.xxxxxxx.mongodb.net/***{Insert DB Name here }***?retryWrites=true&w=majority

The URI you get from mongoDB does not include the DB name.

In my case the DB name is Cosmetics_DB_original